# Created Blender Obj but in OpenGL it loses it's texture?

Tags: c++, opengl, blender

So I've created a 3D model in blender,exported it as an obj and have imported it onto C++/OpenGL. The model loads perfectly although it's lost all of it's colouring and texture. It's just a basic white model.. Is there any way of fixing this or can you not have the model imported with the textures you have to redo them in OpenGl?

Comment: Are you using a library to load the `obj`?

Answer (score 4):

an .obj file does not contain the texture itself: only the texture coordinates per vertex.

you will need to load and bind the texture yourself separately from loading from the obj file.

Other file formats can have a texture embedded but loading models from files is not within the scope of the openGL API.

Answer (score 4):

It's true that `obj` files don't contain textures or material data, but they're commonly paired with `mtl` files. The `obj` references the `mtl` file to use with the `mtllib` directive and chooses materials for subsequent faces with `usemtl`.

See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavefront_.obj_file#Material_template_library

However, the mtl file only contains colours and texture file names, not the actual texture data. You'll have to look into loading textures separately and use it to load the texture referenced in the `mtl` file. Then create the OpenGL texture and draw you object with it bound, together with the texture coordinates in the `obj` file.

In blender, make sure `Write Materials` is checked when exporting the `obj`. Also check the relative paths to the textures are appropriate (just open the `mtl` file in a text editor). As a side note, `Include Normals` is annoyingly is unchecked by default.

So, your `obj` file contains:

- Vertex positions and possibly normals and texture coordinates too.
- Vertex connectivity, or *faces*, which may actually be n-gons and you need to triangulate.
- References to the material file, if there is one.

The `mtl` file contains:

- Many material definitions
- Each identified by a name
- Containing colour for ambient, diffuse, specular etc.
- Also containing texture map references (file names) and could be `png`, `jpg`, whatever.